# Dynamically load HTML template in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, aem, angular-cli, angular2-compiler

I have created a project using `angular-cli` which contains **AppComponent** as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

And **app.component.html** as

```
<h1>
  Good Morning, {{title}}
</h1>
```

So when I build it with `ng build` it generates some files like this **./dist/main.bundle.js** which contents some code as follows-

```
/* 586 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

module.exports = "<h1>\n  Good Morning, {{title}}\n</h1>\n"

/***/ },
/* 587 */
```

That means, at the time of build the compiler/bundle-er is reading the html file and concatenating those into the generated js file.

But in my case the html is also **dynamic** and content-driven from server side. Lets say, instead of html, my template file is **app.component.jsp** and residing on some different server or folder altogether.

Also that JSP file sometimes returns `<h1>Good Morning, {{title}}</h1>`
and sometimes `<h1>Good Afternoon, {{title}}</h1>` depending on current server time.

How to achieve this functionality?

What I understand is that, I need to define some kind of loader function say : `loadDynamicTemplate(template_url)`

and need to use that loader-function on Component decorator template property. In that case, when the main.bundle.JS is generated, it will use that function also. So in runtime angular will call this function and load the HTML by ajax and use it.

**Update 1**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263406/what-are-differences-between-systemjs-and-webpack) I found some difference between SystemJS and Webpack . I also found we can load the HTML files in run-time if we can use SystemJS. So I believe this problem can be solved with SystemJS configuration. But for that another problem comes into play, though I believe that could be a separate question. So I posted a new question to sort it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417832/configure-angular-cli-to-use-systemjs).

Probably if that question get solved I will try with SystemJS and then post solution here if it helps.

Comment: This is not too common in Angular2. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960

Comment: In my case all of my component will have same behavior. And it is really problematic to define all of my component as dynamic. So actually I am looking for like this. `template: "<my-template url='./app.component.html'></my-template>"`. Here `my-template` could be a directive and it will load the HTML dynamically. Aslo it should keep all other functionality intact. As it should work same as `templateUrl: './app.component.html'`

Comment: I understand this is not too common. Actually I have a server side content management system with Adobe AEM. Which I want to use for its great authoring feature. Since Angular2 is a great framework, I am sure there should be some way around. (Without changing so many code Just I want to serve the templates at run-time via AJAX call only). Please help.

Comment: You can load HTML in existing components, but only plain HTML. If you it to become Angular components, directives, or data- or event binding, it has to be in the template of a compiled component.

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh, did you try the ng-dynamic library ? I think it really do the job : https://github.com/laco0416/ng-dynamic

Comment: Yes, I think it could work. Can you please answer with this. So that I can select the answer if I got success.

Comment: Did you ever figure out this AEM and angular 2 (or 4) problem?

Answer (score 39):

You could use [innerHtml] in a `my-template` component with something like this (I didn't test) :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-template',
    template: `
<div [innerHtml]="myTemplate">
</div>
`})
export public class MyTemplate {
    private myTemplate: any = "";
    @Input() url: string;
    constructor(http: Http) {
        http.get("/path-to-your-jsp").map((html:any) => this.myTemplate = html);
    }
}
```

Comment: Something like `Good Morning, {{title}}` won't resolve `{{title}}` this way.

Comment: Well the good Plunker was ever here : https://plnkr.co/edit/uzcYiN I post an example for @Partha Sarathi Ghosh

Comment: How to force the default setup to serve certain html templates from the project folder?

Comment: I don't understand. You may take a look to webpack documentation : https://webpack.github.io/docs/

Comment: @EricBergman could you please explain what didn't work for you ?

Comment: http.get("/path-to-your-jsp").map((html:any) => html = html.text()).subscribe(this.myTemplate = html)

Comment: Angular does not resolve bindings inside [innerHTML], so if `title` changes it does not update correctly.
What you could do is create a `GreetingComponent` that receives raw data from your server and handle it inside Angular.

Comment: hi, it is not working in angular 7. can you please give me some idea  to accomplish this idea.

Answer (score 18):

To interpolate a template with some `Good Morning, {{title}}`, you may use Suguru Inatomi's "ng-dynamic" component.

First you have to install it :

```
npm install --save ng-dynamic
```

Then import into your NgModule :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    DynamicComponentModule.forRoot({}),
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Finally use it like this :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<div *dynamicComponent="template; context: bindings;"></div>'
})
export class AppComponent {
  bindings: any = {title: "Chuck Norris"};
  template: string = `
    <h1>Good Morning, {{title}}</h1>
  `;
  constructor(http: Http) {
    http.get("/path-to-your-jsp").map((html:string) => this.template = html); //<- You may set bindings in request headers...
  }
}
```

You could use components in your template by defining a SharedModule. I added a custom "my-button" with succes like in the documentation example here : https://github.com/laco0416/ng-dynamic

Comment: The way of writing the code here is very complex if I have so many binding variables and methods. Here I found one more info about SystemJs and Webpack. I updated my question with the findings.

Comment: Why do get error: Can't bind to 'dynamicComponent' since it isn't a known property of 'div' ?

Comment: Maybe you miss the star ? `*dynamicComponent`

Comment: getting error on production build "TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined"

Answer (score 3):

worked with angular 6

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
            <div [innerHtml]="myTemplate">
            </div>
          `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private myTemplate: any = '';
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    http.get('/service-path', {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(data => this.myTemplate = data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the way to do this now is to set the responseType when you make your request. [HttpClient-Requesting non-JSON data](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data)
`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-template',
  template: '<div [innerHtml]="myTemplate"></div>'
})
export public class MyTemplate {
  private myTemplate: any = "";
  @Input() url: string;
  constructor(http: Http) {
    http.get("/path-to-your-jsp", { responseType: 'text' })
      .subscribe(
        (data: string) => {
          this.myTemplate = html;
        }
      );
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Why not have all the template in one file and display them according to the condition.. 
Like your ./app.component.html will look like:

```
<div *ngIf="isWorld" >
  <h1>  Hello World </h1>
</div>
<div *ngIf="isUniverse" >
  <h1>  Hello Universe </h1>
</div>
```

Any idea on its effect on build time/size?