# configure angular-cli to use SystemJS

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, systemjs

I know that angular-cli has moved to webpack from SystemJS. But for a specific problem (Posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786490/dynamically-load-html-template-in-angular2)) I need to load/assemble my project at client side, so I prefer SystemJS.

Right now the project is running with angular-cli default configuration and lots of functionality is been developed. So I need a very easy way to move to SystemJS from Webpack.

Can any one please help me regarding that?

Note: I do not want to compromise angular-cli advantages like :code generation, unit test etc.

My angular-cli version is : '1.0.0-beta-21'

**Update 1**

Actually I want to run the same application on SystemJS so that I can deploy that on a different WebServer and load the HTML and TS files run time. Even though the developers will work on angular-cli and webpack.

That means I want my project to run on SystemJS along with webpack and angular-cli.

Comment: You are more than like going to have to go back to a version of the CLI that was using SystemJS. Beta 10, or prior.

Comment: Is it not possible the same project such that it will also run on SystemJS. I just need to use a different npm command.

Comment: Found some way to integrate SystemJS also in Angular CLI which will run beside webpack if needed.

Comment: Are you able to share how you managed to integrate systemjs and angular-cli?

Comment: I will share it soon here as an answer. I am little busy now.

Comment: I have the save issue as you have and its more than month that i am don't find any solution. Did you solves this?

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh Did you find a way?

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh I too would like to see the solution you came up with.  Webpack is missing a feature that I need, but I would like to not give up the cli convinience