# Injecting External Input to Angular2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, code-injection, endpoints

I want to inject an external input (REST API End Point) and would like to use it in my code. However, I just want to build my application once and I should be able to change my End Point based on the deployment I do. In other words, I want my end point to be parameterised in the Prod environment.

I have tried a lot injection methods already mentioned in Stack Overflow but am unable to achieve my result in Prod Environment.

Comment: Can please share some code

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786490/dynamically-load-html-template-in-angular2 ?

Comment: I want to inject the HTTP url before Bootstraping. In this way, I will be able to change the value of the URL based on the environment in which it is going to be deployed.