# Relative references break when loading external HTML to Angular 2 component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a server that hosts simple HTML like the following:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
   <img src="img/main.PNG"/>
</a>
```

The src attribute of the IMG tag contains the relative location of the file I want to show. This works perfectly when opening with a browser.

The problem is that when I load it with angular, Angular tries to resolve that relative location locally, which obviously won't work.
I followed the tips given here in SO. For example [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786490/dynamically-load-html-template-in-angular2).

What I have now:

HTML:

```
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

TypeScript:

```
this.myService.subscribe(
  (html: any) => {
     this.content = html._body;
     this.loaded = true;
  },
  err => {
    this.error = true;
  });
```

If I change the HTML on the server to return the absolute URL of the image then it works:

```
 <img src="http://localhost:5500/img/main.PNG"/>
```

This, however, is not a feasible solution in my case.

So my question is:
Is there a way to load HTML content from an external source with Angular 2 in a way that won't broke relative references in said HTML?

Comment: Have you tried "./img/main.PNG"?

Comment: That... is embarrassing. It works, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `"img/main.PNG"` to `"./img/main.PNG"`